# Android UI using XML (Android and Xml)

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am tying to create a UI like the image below.

This is how it SHOULD look like: (Screen shot from my app using Nexsus 5):

[image]

And this is how it look like on a Nexsus S device (4 inch):

[image]

Someone have an idea why the diffrences happen? This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2e2e2e"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/viewew">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"

            >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/www"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:background="@drawable/www"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/www"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:background="@drawable/www"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/www"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/www"

                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/idd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_weight="2"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Doesn't belong here?"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/buttons" />





    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" here?"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
        android:id="@+id/tDoesntBelongHere"
        />

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eee"
        tools:context=".MyActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android studio you have to set the screen size for different devices.

your buttons have this: 
                `android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"`

So whichever screen you are using the size will always be 90dp.

In android studio you can create more xml pages for same page: one for portrait, for landscape, ecc ecc and also one for small-big-xxl ecc screen.

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link from android developer site.

Hope it help :)

EDIT:

At the moment i don't have Android studio in the pc i'm working on, so i try to explain a possible solution.

Instead of setting height and width, set margins:
You can anchor all from botside, adding in your TextView `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` (and a margin-bottom if you want). Then keep your view with a static height of 400dp like now, then anchor it to the top of the TextView by `android:layout_above="@id/TextViewId` (it doesn't have id, add it)

Now you have to do the same with your LinearLayout: use `android:layout_above="@id/idd` and removing the the static size. At this point you can just let your buttons to set `height` equals to the LinearLayout's `height` (obiouvsly you can set `margin` top-bot in buttons).

Sorry if my english is not that good, i hope u got the solution

Comment: Thank  you for a quick reply :)
So how sould I call to the directory for 4'' screen sizes?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: I read it, and now my problem is that Nexus S and Nexus 5 are in the same catagory of "Layout-Normal" (around 4 inch) so what can I do?

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot! +1